# Setting a custom return address header

Tags: rebus

I need to set a custom return-address as described here https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Return-addresses but there's no attachheader option anymore.

How do I achieve this in rebus2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All methods on `IBus` that send messages have an optional parameter that accepts a headers dictionary.

Therefore, you can simply

```
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { Headers.ReturnAddress, "wherever" }
};

await bus.Send(yourMessage, headers);
```

in order to set a custom return address :)

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that I tried that already - but it doesn't seem to overwrite the default.

I use MessageContext.Current.Headers to check the return-address in my handler.

Comment: Can you tell some more about what you are doing? I don't get what you mean by "I use MessageContext.Current.Headers to check the return-address in my handler" ... :-S

Comment: I just used MessageContext.Current.Headers[Headers.Headers.ReturnAddress] to see if the return address had changed. Anyway, it's all good. Turned out my test setup was a bit too simplistic, as I was using bus.sendlocal *eyesrolling*. When using bus.send everything works - great! :-)

Comment: Excellent :) :) :)